# merging CSV streams with node, trying to emit a header once and only once

Tags: node.js, csv

Using Node.js and [NodeCSV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv).

I am looping over multiple CSV streams, and trying to merge them into a single CSV, with a header line as the first line. I am also filtering to get only records whose `time` column is later than a given time, though I am pretty sure this part isn't relevant to my problem.

The input CSVs have header lines, and some of them might not contain the expected columns, in which case they should pass through without emitting any records.

The code (modified for brevity, please excuse copy/paste/munge errors) is like this:

```
const csv = require('csv');
let header = true; // first record should emit a header line
const streams = [_array, _of, _read, _streams];
const lastIndex = streams.length - 1;
const sinceTime = Date.parse(someTime);
for (const [i, s] of streams.entries()) {
    s
        .pipe(csv.parse({columns: true}))
        .pipe(csv.transform(function (record) {
            const recordTime = Date.parse(record.time);
            if (recordTime > sinceTime) {
                return record;
            }
        }))
        .pipe(csv.stringify({
            columns: ['time', 'col'],
            header: header
        }))
        .pipe(output, {end: i === lastIndex});

    // this should only be cleared if the file actually emitted a header, but how do I know!?
    header = false;
}
```

The problem occurs when the first input file doesn't contain the `time` and `col` columns, let's say it's a csv with `X` and `Y` columns instead.

In this case, the file emits no records (as desired) but as a result it emits no header line, either.  But I don't know that, and happily set the `header` boolean to `false`.  Then my output contains no header line, which is not what I want.

If the first file is with the expected columns `time` and `col`, everything is great, and I get the header line from the first file.

How can I handle this case, and emit a header line even if the first file emits no records?

**Update:**

I thought of the following solution, which works, but it seems like there must be a better way.  I tried generating an empty CSV with a header before the loop, like this:

```
const csv = require('csv');
const streams = [_array, _of, _read, _streams];
const lastIndex = streams.length - 1;
const sinceTime = Date.parse(someTime);
const columns = ['time', 'col'];

// generate the header line with an empty CSV
csv
    .generate({length: 0})
    .pipe(csv.parse({columns: true}))
    .pipe(csv.stringify({
        columns: columns,
        header: true
    }))
    .pipe(output, {end: false});

for (const [i, s] of streams.entries()) {
    s
        .pipe(csv.parse({columns: true}))
        .pipe(csv.transform(function (record) {
            const recordTime = Date.parse(record.time);
            if (recordTime > sinceTime) {
                return record;
            }
        }))
        .pipe(csv.stringify({
            columns: columns,
            header: false
        }))
        .pipe(output, {end: i === lastIndex});
}
```

Ugly, but it's doing what I want it to do. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Is it not possible to check the header in the callback function of the `csv.parse({columns:true})`?

Comment: @Geshode - I am afraid I don't follow you.  Check the header how, and what do I do with it?  I need to know whether to emit a header line in the `csv.stringify()` call... can you explain with pseudo-code/

Comment: I saw [this example](https://github.com/adaltas/node-csv-parse/blob/master/samples/option.columns.true.js). I thought, it would be possible to take the `records` object from the callback function (starting at line 10) and check the keys of it, which are the column names in the header. That way you could know, if the headers are `time` and `col` as wanted or not,